# WCF ChannelFactory.CreateChannel()

Tags: c#, wcf

Why is it I'm able to do this:

```
var _channel = new ChannelFactory<T>("bindingname").CreateChannel();
```

But not this

```
var _channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>("bindingname");
var _channel = _channelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

The 2nd snippet complains that I need to pass in an `EndPointAddress` in `CreateChannel()` whereas the 1st doesn't.

Aren't the 2 snippets essentially the same?

Comment: I'm not getting the same results you are, as in your code works on my test machine (VS 2012, .NET 4.5)... What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: I'm using .NET 4.0 with VS2010

Comment: Is it at runtime or intellisense?

Comment: both. I can't compile. I'll get 

No overload for method 'CreateChannel' takes 0 arguments

Comment: I'm at a loss here, I tried it on my VS 2010 system, and it works just fine.  I tried googling it as well, I don't see anything on it... maybe there is an update you are missing, or a service pack?

Comment: Something else is going on here.  Can you post a more complete example?

Comment: This is my full source http://pastebin.com/7FNnfuFR

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might be because `var _channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>("bindingname");`
is resolving _channelFactory to `IChannelFactory<T>` instead of `ChannelFactory<T>`.

Try

```
ChannelFactory<T> _channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>("bindingname");
var _channel = _channelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

[ChannelFactory<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132(v=vs.100).aspx) has a CreateChannel() method that takes no parameters. [IChannelFactory<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(%22SYSTEM.SERVICEMODEL.CHANNELS.ICHANNELFACTORY%601%22);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true) does not have a CreateChannel() method that takes no parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the signature for the constructors for ChannelFactory, the only one that takes a single string as an input is asking for an endpointConfigurationName - not a binding name. Could this be the root of your problem? You may be constructing the ChannelFactory incorrectly? See below:-

```
    public ChannelFactory();
    public ChannelFactory(Binding binding);
    public ChannelFactory(ServiceEndpoint endpoint);
    public ChannelFactory(string endpointConfigurationName);
    protected ChannelFactory(Type channelType);
    public ChannelFactory(Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress);
    public ChannelFactory(Binding binding, string remoteAddress);
    public ChannelFactory(string endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress);
```